# .Contains not retrieving the desired value in parent child condition

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `employee table`(ParentTable) and `employee centers table`(Child Table).Each employee is allotted different centers.When an employee login, I want to show all employee which are 
added to his center.

For example:-

```
Center       Employee
 A,B,C          X
  B             Y
  C             Z
```

When `Employee X` login he should be able to view `Y & Z`.But when `Employee Y` login he **should not** view `Emp Z`.`Emp Y`should only view employees added to `Center B` which is `X & Y`.

This is what i've tried but could not get the desired result

```
//Gets all the centerCodeIds allotted to an employee
List<int> _centerCodeIds = _cmn.GetCenterEmpwise(Convert.ToInt32(Session["LoggedUserId"]))
                               .Select(x => x.Id).ToList();

var _dTableEmployee
   = _db.Employees
        .Where(x => x.Status == true &&
        /* Checking condition  */  
       _centerCodeIds.Contains(x.EmployeeCenters.FirstOrDefault().Id))
        .AsEnumerable()
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Id)
        .Select(x => new
        {
            SlNo = "",
            Name = x.Name,
            CenterCode = x.EmployeeCenters
                     .Select(ec => ec.CenterCode.CentreCode)
                     .Aggregate((m, n) => m + "," + n),
            Designation = x.Designation.DesignationName,
            EmailId = x.OfficialEmailId,
            Mobile = x.OfficialMobileNo != null ? x.OfficialMobileNo : x.MobileNo,
            Id = x.Id
        });
```

Comment: Given your example you show that `X` "belongs" to `A,B,C` wouldn't that make `X` visible for `Y`? In my eyes it seems like everyone can see `X` and `X` can see everyone in this given example?
Or are you saying that if an employee has more than one they should be considered invisible for everyone else?

Comment: Is that LINQ to objects or Linq to SQL (ex. Entity Framework)?

Comment: @Ricky you are right,I have updated the question `everyone can see X`

Comment: @Shaamaan its Linq to SQL (ex. Entity Framework)

Answer (score 0):

since 1 employee can help multiple centers, I think you should use **intersect** to check

```
/* Checking condition  */  
_centerCodeIds.Intersect(x.EmployeeCenters.Select(c => c.Id))).Any()
```

Testing:

```
var centerCodeIds = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3}; // X, Y, Z
var employeeCodeIds = new List<int> { 2, 4, 5}; // Z, A, B
centerCodeIds.Intersect(employeeCodeIds).Any(); // return true
centerCodeIds.Intersect(employeeCodeIds); // return 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I do agree with the previous answerer. Using Intersect should provide you the correct answer you want. Have you tried using it like this?

```
List<int> _centerCodeIds = _cmn.GetCenterEmpwise(Convert.ToInt32(Session["LoggedUserId"]))
                           .Select(x => x.Id).ToList();

var _dTableEmployee
= _db.Employees
    .Where(x => x.Status == true && 
           x.EmployeeCenters.Select(x => x.Id).Intersect(_centerCodeIds))
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Id)
    .Select(x => new
    {
        SlNo = "",
        Name = x.Name,
        CenterCode = x.EmployeeCenters
                 .Select(ec => ec.CenterCode.CentreCode)
                 .Aggregate((m, n) => m + "," + n),
        Designation = x.Designation.DesignationName,
        EmailId = x.OfficialEmailId,
        Mobile = x.OfficialMobileNo != null ? x.OfficialMobileNo : x.MobileNo,
        Id = x.Id
    });
```